# Cual es mi problema con mi array

Tags: c

Hola soy nuevo y quisiera saber si alguien me puede asesorar con mi problema tengo que generar números aleatorios
En total 34 y separarlos entre 60 a 69 ,70 a 79,80 a 89
Trate de utilizar el array con un if que limite la entrada de los datos del rango de a 69 y almacenarlos en otro  array para que guarde los datos  y agrego un contador para que me mencione cuantos datos entran ahí
El problema es que cuando quiero usar nuevamente el array principal y utilizarlo con otro if se cierra
Ya intente copiando el array original a un auxiliar pero sigue sin funcionarme
Soy nuevo con esto ,alguien me podría decir mi error?

````
     int v[34];
     int n6=1,j;
     int n7=1,k;
     int aux[34],alums6[34],alums7[34];
     
srand(time(NULL));  
    
    for(int i = 1; i < 35; i++)
    {
      v[i] = 60 + rand() % (91 - 60);
      printf("\t%d ",v[i]);
      
    }//Llenado de array con numeros aleatorios entre 60 a 90
  
 

for (int i = 1; i<35; i++){

  if(v[i]<=69){
 
 n6++;
 alums6[j]=v[i];
 j++;
 
}
}// fin del ciclo de Alumnos con peso de 60 a 69

for (int i = 1; i<35; i++){

  if((v[i]>69)&&(v[i]<=79)){
 
 n7++;
 alums7[k]=v[i];
 k++;
 
}
}//Fin del ciclo de alumnos con peso de 70 a 79


    
for(int v=1; v<n6; v++){

printf("\n %d",alums6[v]);

}//Impresion de pesos menor a 69



for(int i=1;i<n7; i++){

printf("\n aa %d",alums7[i]);

}//Impresion de pesos entre 70 y 79


return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que escribes fuera de los arrays.

Aquí, por ejemplo, declaras un array con capacidad para 34 enteros:

```
int v[34];
```

El acceso a dichos enteros se realiza a través de los índices del rango (0, 33).

Aquí es donde rellenas el array:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 35; i++)
{
  v[i] = 60 + rand() % (91 - 60);
  printf("\t%d ",v[i]);
  
}
```

Fíjate que estás iterando en el rango (1, 34). Este rango no es el mismo que te he indicado yo y ello implica dos cosas:

1. Estás dejando la posición 0 sin usar (desperdicias un poco de memoria)
2. Escribes en la posición 34, que no pertenece al array. Esta posición de memoria puede ser ocupada en cualquier momento por otra variable, esto puede provocar que pierdas información y que tu programa se vuelva errático, ya que sobreescribes valores que no deberías.

Y este error lo repites en cada bucle, así que grábate a fuego esta consigna:

> Los índices empiezan **siempre** en 0

Por otro lado, dado que dices ser nuevo, te sugiero adquirir un hábito que te evitará numerosos dolores de cabeza: A la hora de declarar variables, piensa un nombre adecuado. Es posible que ahora con 4 variables no te lies, pero imagínate un programa con cientos de variables y todas con nombres tipo `n6`, `n7`, `i`, `j` ... te vas a volver loco